# How to properly merge lambda-expressions with different parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have two expressions :

```
Expression<Func<long, bool>> condition = x => x < max; // Exp # 1

if (count > 0)
{
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> limit = x => x > -1; // Exp # 2
    condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<long, bool>>(
                Expression.AndAlso(condition, limit), condition.Parameters);
}

var comparator = condition.Compile();

while (comparator(k++, n--))
{
    // Something
}
```

The following code compiles but it takes only one parameter of type "long" into combined lambda, how can I pass two different parameters into combined lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<long, bool>> condition = x => x < max; // Exp # 1
Expression<Func<long, int, bool>> combined = null;

if (count > 0)
{
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> limit = x => x > -1; // Exp # 2
    combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<long, int, bool>>(
        Expression.And(condition.Body, limit.Body), 
        new ParameterExpression[] 
        {
            condition.Parameters[0], 
            limit.Parameters[0] 
        }
    );
} else {
    // Count <= 0, `int` parameter will be provided, but `body` ignores it
    combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<long, int, bool>>(
        condition.Body, 
        new ParameterExpression[] 
        {
            condition.Parameters[0], 
            limit.Parameters[0] 
        }
    );
}

// compile `combined` expression
var comparator = combined.Compile();

while (comparator(k++, n--))
{
    // Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make `condition` an expression with two inputs. When not combining with the second expression, add a second (unused) parameter to lambda definition. When combining two expressions, add `Invoke` around the expressions that you are combining. Otherwise you are going to get a runtime error telling you that `Func<int,bool>` and `Func<long,bool>` cannot be combined with `&&` operator.

Here is how you can implement it:

```
Expression<Func<long,int,bool>> condition;

Expression<Func<long,bool>> exp1 = x => x < max;

if (count > 0)
{
    Expression<Func<int,bool>> exp2 = x => x > -1;
    condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<long,int,bool>>(
            Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.Invoke(exp1, exp1.Parameters)
            ,   Expression.Invoke(exp2, exp2.Parameters)
            )
        ,   exp1.Parameters.Concat(exp2.Parameters)
        );
} else {
    condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<long,int,bool>>(
        Expression.Invoke(exp1, exp1.Parameters)
        ,   exp1.Parameters.Concat(new[]{Expression.Parameter(typeof(int))})
        );
}
var comparator = condition.Compile();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YsMmE8)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio handy right now, but on a hunch did you try this to see if it works:

```
if (count > 0)
{
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> limit = x => x > -1; // Exp # 2
    condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<long, int, bool>>(
                Expression.AndAlso(condition, limit), condition.Parameters);
}
```

That would give the new combined Lambda a signature that accepts two parameters and returns a bool. You may also need to do something after `condition.Parameters` to include l`imit.parameters` also.

Comment: This will compile, but it will break at runtime, because `condition` and `limit` are `Func<...>` objects, meaning that the `&&` operator "AndAlso" cannot be applied to them.